# OnPropertyChanged not fire with label text

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding

I am in a Xamarin app I which I have to make a to-do list. I am using listview. I have to set a label text dynamically every time I add a new to-do like so: Number of tasks 2/4 where 2 are the done tasks and 4 are the total ones. Everything goes right but I found some issues when I have to update the label text. I am using the MVVM pattern. In XAML I bind the text value to SetInfoDoneText. In MainPage, I have the bindigContext set to VM(TodoListViewModel).  I use INotifyPropertyChanged with OnPropertyChanged. I made a method in which the value of setInfoDoneText is changed. The problem is that the set and get is called only once and when the setInfoDoneText is updated by the method OnPropertyChanged does not fire again. Here is the code.
THE PROBLEM IS WHEN I TRY TO UPDATE lblDoneInfo text (
)
class TodoListViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

```
    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> todoItems { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public String setInfoDoneText;
    public String SetInfoDoneText
    {
        get => setInfoDoneText;
        set
        {

            setInfoDoneText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SetInfoDoneText");
        }

    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
   
    int doneTask = 0;
    int totalTask = 0;
    public TodoListViewModel()
    {
       
        this.todoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        setInfoDoneText = "Number of tasks: " + doneTask + "/" + totalTask;
       
        

    }

    public ICommand AddTodoCommand => new Command(AddTodoItem);

    public String newTodoInputValue { get; set; }
    public String selectedItem { get; set; }
    public  bool highPriority { get; set; }
    public  bool midPriority { get; set; }
    public  bool lowPriority { get; set; }
   



    Color newColor = new Color();
    public void AddTodoItem()
    {
       
        if (highPriority)
        {
            newColor = Color.Red;
            AddNewItem(newColor);
            highPriority = false;


        }
        if (midPriority)
        {
            newColor = Color.Orange;
            AddNewItem(newColor);
            midPriority = false;

        }
        if (lowPriority) 
        {
            newColor = Color.Yellow;
            AddNewItem(newColor);
            lowPriority = false;
        }
       
        

    

        
    }
    public TodoItem AddNewItem(Color newColor)
    {
        
        TodoItem newItem = new TodoItem(newTodoInputValue,
           false,
           highPriority,
           midPriority,
           lowPriority,
           newColor);

        
        todoItems.Add(newItem);
        UpdateDoneInfo();

        return newItem;
    }

    public ICommand RemoveTodoCommand => new Command(RemoveTodoItem);

    public void RemoveTodoItem(object o)
    {
        TodoItem todoItemBeingRemoved = o as TodoItem;
       
        todoItems.Remove(todoItemBeingRemoved);
    }

    public ICommand EditTodoCommand => new Command(EditTodoItem);
    public void EditTodoItem(object o)
    {


        TodoItem todoItemBeingEdited = o as TodoItem;
        int newIndex = todoItems.IndexOf(todoItemBeingEdited);
        todoItems.Remove(todoItemBeingEdited);

        TodoItem updatedTodo = AddNewItem(newColor);
        //todoItems.Add(updatedTodo);

        int oldIndex = todoItems.IndexOf(updatedTodo);
        todoItems.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);

    }

    public String UpdateDoneInfo()
    {



        totalTask = todoItems.Count;

        foreach (TodoItem item in todoItems)
        {
            if (item.complete) doneTask++;
        }


        return setInfoDoneText = "Number of tasks: " + doneTask + "/" + totalTask;
    }


}
```

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:TodoListViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>


<StackLayout>
   
  
    <Entry 
        x:Name="inputField"
        Text="{Binding newTodoInputValue}" 
        Placeholder="Enter a todo..."
        

    />


    <Label x:Name="lblDoneInfo" Text="{Binding SetInfoDoneText, Mode=TwoWay }">
        
    </Label>

    <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
        <input:CheckBox x:Name="highP" 
                        IsChecked="{Binding highPriority}" 
                        CheckChangedCommand="{Binding AddTodoCommand}" 
                        Margin="0,0,20,0" />
        <Label Text="High Priority" FontSize="Medium"/>

        <input:CheckBox x:Name="midP" 
                       IsChecked="{Binding midPriority}"
                       CheckChangedCommand="{Binding AddTodoCommand}"  
                       Margin="0,0,20,0" />
        <Label Text="Medium Priority" FontSize="Medium"/>

        <input:CheckBox x:Name="lowP"  
                        IsChecked="{Binding lowPriority}"  
                        CheckChangedCommand="{Binding AddTodoCommand}"  
                        Margin="0,0,20,0" />
        <Label Text="Low Priority" FontSize="Medium"/>
    </FlexLayout>
     


    
    <ListView x:Name="todoList" ItemsSource="{Binding todoItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem}">
        
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="20">
                    
                    <FlexLayout JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"  AlignItems="Center" Padding="20,0">
                        <ContentView>
                            <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center">
                                <input:CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding complete}" Margin="5" />
                                <Label x:Name="todoText" TextColor="{Binding color}" Text="{Binding todoText}" FontSize="Large"/>
                            </FlexLayout>
                            

                        </ContentView>

                        <ImageButton 
                            Source="editar_24.png"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            WidthRequest="100"
                            HeightRequest="100"
                            Margin="0,0,20,0"
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditTodoCommand,
                                        Source={x:Reference todoList}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                        
                        <ImageButton 
                        
                            Source="basura_24.png"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            WidthRequest="100"
                            HeightRequest="100"
                           
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveTodoCommand, 
                                        Source={x:Reference todoList}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
  
                    </FlexLayout>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

`PropertyChanged` only fires when you set the value of the **public property** `SetInfoDoneText`.  Your code is setting the value of the field `setInfoDoneText` (lowercase).

It is generally best practice to make the field `private` to prevent this

```
private String setInfoDoneText;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! But I tried to change setInfoDoneText with capital S and now the app runs but closes inmediatly...Don't know why... I thinks that falls into an inifite loop or something like this.

Comment: you ONLY need to change it in `UpdateDoneInfo` and the VM constructor.  If you change it inside the property setter you will create an infinite loop that will crash the app

Comment: That was the point!!! Many thanks for your time! My best wishes from Spain!

Comment: One more question if you don't mind to answer! How can i bind my checkbos from the listview to a command from the viewmodel. What I am trying to achieve is to change the same label as before but now according to the checked to-dos from listview. The problem is that if I try to bind as normally in listview to viewmodel it doesnt trigger the command function.

Comment: please post a new question with the relevant code